# Mobile App for Journaling

Tags: android, collaboration, notification, directories, journal

About this app, main requirements:

- some sort of content aggregation or folders( personal, work, family, couple, etc)
- have private and shareable journals
- get notifications when others edit or add new entries
- (optional) read status per entry